# Prime spiral with regular triangles

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I wrote a little program that creates a Ulam like spiral, only with regular triangles instead of squares. The following image shows the way it is set up:

[image: small spiral]

In this set up all the uneven numbers will be represented by a downward pointing triangle. All prime numbers will be represented by a colored triangle.

Now if we make the spiral bigger, we see some interesting patterns emerging:

[image: big spiral]

A few observations:

1. much like Ulam's spiral the prime numbers tend to be on diagonals
2. the diagonals that go from bottom left to top right appear much clearer in the bottom left and center triangular part of the spiral as wel as in the top center and right part. The top left and bottom right triangular parts have more of the diagonals that go from bottom right to top left, but they are not that well defined
3. the diagonals that go from bottom left to top right seem to be the only lines where there are more than 3 primes in a row (if we exclude the first two primes in the center)
4. there are a few diagonals that go from bottom right to top left that have 3 primes in a row, these seem to only appear on the horizontal line that goes through the center of the spiral
5. the vertical lines from 7 down and from 13 up seem to have no primes on them

Any thoughts or explanations? Do the same theories about the Ulam spiral apply to this one?

**Update:**

If I rotate the bottom half of the spiral 180 degrees around the center, such that the vertical 'prime free' lines of 7 and 13 are on top of eachother, another strange 'prime free' line appears from the center to just below the middle of the right side:

[image]

Comment: Are each diagonal's entries the image of some quadratic function? Does it factor for the "empty" diagonals?

Comment: @user7530 Indeed the diagonals are the image of functions in the form of $an^2 \pm bn \pm c$, where $a$ is $6$ and $c$ any odd integer. For the well defined prime diagonals (bottom left to top right) we have $b = 0$ or $b = 6$ and $3\nmid c$. For the less well defined ones (bottom right to top left) we have $b = 2$ or $b = 4$. I'm still curious though why the less well defined prime diagonals can't seem to have more than 2 primes in a row. Can we get that from the quadratic equation?

Comment: The value of $6n^2+2n+c$ is not prime when it is divisible by $3$, unless it equals $3$.  We can solve $6n^2+2n+c=0\pmod{3}$ by reducing it to $2n+c=0\pmod{3}$ and then noticing that $2$ is relatively prime to $3$, and therefore has a multiplicative inverse modulo $3$, namely $2$.  Hence it is equivalent to $n+2c=0\pmod{3}$.  If $c=0\pmod{3}$, then every $n=0\pmod{3}$ is a solution; if $c=1\pmod{3}$, then every $n=1\pmod{3}$ is a solution; if $c=2\pmod{3}$, then every $n=2\pmod{3}$ is a solution.  Therefore, for any $c$, every third $n$ will be a solution

Comment: Also, the prominent vertical prime-free stripe in the upper half is due to three consecutive polynomials of the form $n^2-5n+c$ that factorize: $6n^2-5n-1=(6n+1)(n-1)$, $6n^2-5n=(6n-5)n$, and $6n^2-5n+1=(3n-1)(2n-1$.  Similarly, the prime-free vertical stripe in the lower half is due to $6n^2+n-2=(3n+2)(2n-1)$, $6n^2+n-1=(3n-1)(2n+1)$, and $6n^2+n=(6n+1)n$.  Replacing $n$ with $-n$ in these expressions produces polynomials that are responsible for the prime-free stripe that makes an angle of $30^\circ$ with respect to the horizontal.

Comment: It's worth adding that the polynomials in the comment above are integer-valued for half-integer $n$.  In fact, the polynomials corresponding to the vertical stripe in the lower half are obtained from the polynomials for the vertical stripe in the upper half by the substitution $n\rightarrow n+\frac{1}{2}$.  So the vertical prime-free stripes in the top and bottom halves and the stripes (in both directions) making a $30^\circ$ angle with the horizontal are all a single phenomenon.

Comment: Have you considered using hexagons instead of triangles?